# How to print a double with two decimals only when needed

Tags: java

I want to format following values as I described below:

double d = 1234 
result should be 1,234

double d = 1234.0 
result should be 1,234

double d = 1234.5 
result should be 1,234.50

I tried this method

```
NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#,##.##");
nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
System.out.println(nf.format(d1));
```

but it doesn't work when the value is 1234 or 1234 .0

Comment: you should write different code for decimal point value and non decimal point value

Comment: @AbhishekPatel: absolutely!

Comment: What about the rounded case? e.g. 1234.001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like Bathsheba's solution, but if you want 1234.001 to also be viewed as 1234:

```
NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
String s = nf.format(d1);
if (s.endsWith(".00")) {
  s = s.substring(0, s.length()-3);
}
```

Comment: I like Bathsheba's answer too but I think this is what i want. Your solution works with little change 
    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");

Thanks.

Comment: @MilanJayawardane no problem - I updated the answer with your fix

Answer (score 3):

This kind of thing is an pain to do with one formatter. Consider using

```
if (d1 % 1.0 == 0.0/*yeah, this ain't quick, but then neither is I/O*/){
    // I'm a whole number, floating point modulus is valid in Java.
    // And this is a remarkably good way of testing if a floating
    // point value is a whole number.
    // Format to 0 decimal places.
} else {
    // Format to 2 decimal places.
}
```

Comment: I guess you're ok with 1234.001 looking like 1234.00?

Comment: @ScottAMiller I didn't notice that. Nope, I want it to be 1234.

Comment: @MilanJayawardane I'd suggest my answer then, let the format handle rounding, and then remove 0s if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try like This

```
NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#,##.##");
System.out.println(nf.format(d1));

if(d-(int)d==0){
   System.out.println(d);
}
else{
   System.out.println(nf.format(d));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.printf("%.0f",34.0f);
```

Comment: please explain this answer a bit. code only answers are mostly not of much value. thank u! keep up the good work!

Answer (score 0):

You can check different conditions and define formatting accordingly

```
double d = 1234.5;
        String inp[] = Double.toString(d).split("\\.");
        if((inp.length ==1 &&(inp[1] =="0" )) || inp.length ==0){
            NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
            System.out.println(nf.format(d));
        }else {
            NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#,###.##");
            nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
            nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
            System.out.println(nf.format(d));
        }
```